# Is there a way to persist a logged-in user in React/Redux without using redux-persist or similar middleware?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I am setting my Redux state to be the user object of the user that is logged in (coming from my backend database).

This is what that reducer looks like:

```js
const initialState = {
  user: {},

}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case LOGIN_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload
      }
...
```

With the payload from LOGIN_USER being the user object of the user who logged in.

Now using this state tree, every time I refresh or hit a new route the state is wiped and I am left with an empty object for the 'user' state. I know that there is middleware like redux-persist that aims to solve this issue but I can recall seeing/hearing of projects that do not use this middleware to persist their logged in user state.

Is there any way that I can persist my logged in user throughout refresh/route changes using my current build? Or would I need to somehow change my build to get it to work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using jwt-token-based authentication?

Comment: @RohitKashyap No, I'm not

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most trivial approach is:

```js
store.subscribe(() => {
    const {user} = store.getState();
    localStorage.set("user", JSON.stringify(user));
});
```